# Kile: multiple .tex documents won't compile

Tags: kile

In **Kile**, I have two unrelated .tex documents open. For some reason, when I am on the second one and I try to compile it with `PDFLaTex`, it compiles the first one. `ViewPDF` also will open the first document.

How can I specify that I want the ***current*** document to be compiled and shown?

Comment: Which version of Kile, which OS? Did you make the first document "master"?

Comment: Kile 2.1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't remember setting any document as master, nor do I know how to do it! In the end I closed all documents, closed Kile, reopened it on two other separate documents and now it seems to work. No idea why, though!